# Node/Express (Mongo) Passing of Done ("Done is not a function" error)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Receiving the error “done is not a function.” Yes, I did google and see similar forum posts. :slight_smile: I am fairly sure I am passing done correctly to my function (which was the issue in the posts), although that may not be the case. [Forked repl.lit for editing here.](https://repl.it/join/zapunlox-themagicbean)

Edit:  I was not passing two arguments.  But if you look at the comment to the answer, passing two arguments, with the second being "done" is not working.  I would really appreciate a link or instruction.

Edit 2:  I had mistakenly assumed done was integrated into the framework I was using, which it wasn't.

Relevant code:

```
var shortURLNumber = 0;

function createAndSaveURL(htmlInput, done) {

shortURLNumber++;

console.log("In create and save, shortURLNumber is "+shortURLNumber);

const shortURLhere = ('/api/shorturl/' + shortURLNumber);

var urlToSave = NewURL({long: htmlInput, short: shortURLhere});

urlToSave.save (function(err, data) {
  if (err) {return console.error(err)};
  done(null, data);  //this is the line throwing an error according to the console
});

};
```

and:

```
app.post('/api/shorturl/new', urlParser, (req, res) => {
//console.log("post url of " + req.body["url"]);

createAndSaveURL(req.body["url"]); 

res.json({
  url: req.body["url"]

 });
});
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: The example doesn't pass a second argument to `createAndSaveURL()`, so it's `undefined`

Comment: Attempted to pass a second argument, please see comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have created a function with two required params and you passing only one.
but seems you want second param optional.

you can add if before invoke it.

```js
function createAndSaveURL(htmlInput, done) {
  // --- line of code ---
  if(done) done()
}
```

or can pass second param while calling the function like:

```js
createAndSaveURL(req.body["url"], ()=>{
   // --- do something cool
})
```

Or you can define default value to make any param optional

```js
function createAndSaveURL(htmlInput, done=Function) {
  // --- line of code ---
  if(done) done()
}
```

for more [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: The first proposed solution results in the same error.  I am unclear as to how to implement the second.  The third results in "done is not defined."

Answer (score 0):

The key issue was not defining done, which admittedly was not 'done' (forgive the pun) in any linked or sampled code.  (So passing two arguments was relevant but not a complete solution.)  In any case, to whomever is unfortunate enough to see this, be sure that copypasta from previous works includes such things.